# what type of sql agent jobs are these with weird name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Name of the job is :- E14DF5CB-E9A1-49B7-9ECD-A1EDBFC7993E
and there are many more like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `job_id` may have been used as the name, you will have to dig into it yourself.

Start by looking in [msdb.dbo.sysjobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    job_id, 
    name, 
    date_created, 
    date_modified, 
    job_owner=suser_sname(owner_sid)
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
WHERE job_id = 'E14DF5CB-E9A1-49B7-9ECD-A1EDBFC7993E'
OR name = 'E14DF5CB-E9A1-49B7-9ECD-A1EDBFC7993E'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it. These are system generated report server jobs which gets created as soon as you will configure reporting service config manager.